# how to show original xml-style text in jqgrid without parsing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, xml-parsing

I need to show data in jqGrid from a database table that stores the statistics for XML messages of web services. I need to display the date and text messages in the initial form of XML with tags, etc. ie, the column "XML response message" should contain records like

```
<rsp> <to>123</to><from>321</from> <body>Error003</body> </rsp>
```

FF console shows that the response data is correct(original XML-style string), but the form displays the following string  "123321Error003" (ie parsed xml data). What parameters hould i specify for jqGrid to show the message in its original style (display xml-strings on the form as stored in the database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that jqGrid option [autoencode: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) will solve your problem.